# Obtener el valor del id

Tags: javascript, framework7

Estoy aprendiendo a usar FrameWork7 y en general a programar en JavaScript, existe un componente que tiene el nombre de "accordion" (https://framework7.io/docs/accordion.html#dom-events), cuando el usuario abra un elemento, debo de identificar cual fue para posteriormente trabajar con la API que desplegará determinada información dentro de dicho elemento.

El componente tiene sus eventos, el sig. ejemplo es un evento para identificar cuando abren alguno de sus elementos, ignoro que significa "el".

```
app7.on('accordionOpen',function (el) {
  console.log(el);
};
```

La impresión que hace la consola con el ejemplo anterior cuando se abre un elemento del accordion es el siguiente...

```
<li class="accordion-item">
          <a class="item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title" id="numero_jornada">Jornada 1</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="block" id="show-resul-jor-1">

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

La pregunta es .... cómo puedo obtener el id del html que se me está imprimiendo en la consola?, me queda claro que con getElementById lo puedo hacer, pero para usar getElementById tengo que usar document.getElementById y esto no es lo que busco, ya que el id="numero_jornada" se usa para todos los elementos del accordion y document lo buscará en todo el DOM, yo solo quiero el ID del elemento que el usuario abrió.

Me pueden ayudar de favor ? Gracias!

Comment: Podrías Intentar cambiando un poco la estructura, agregar name="numero_jornada"  a todos tus items y para el id que le corresponda  agregar un valor id="numero_jornada_1" , id="numero_jornada_2" con eso ya son diferentes. Aunque no entiendo para que necesitas saber que item fue seleccionado.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

De entrada, tienes un problema, porque dices:

> id="numero_jornada" se usa para todos los elementos del accordion

Y [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id) es muy clara al respecto:

> El atributo global id define un **identificador único (ID)** el cual **no debe repetirse en todo el documento**. Su propósito es identificar el elemento al vincularlo (usando un identificador de fragmento), en scripts u hojas de estilo (con CSS).

Como bien et sugiere @Cesarin en comentarios, debes asignar diferente ID para cada elemento.

Para acceder al contenido, puedes usar el argumento recibido por le función que, en teoría, es el elemento del DOM que disparó el evento, en este caso, `<li class="accordion-item">...</item>`, con el método [element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector):

```
app7.on('accordionOpen',function (el) {
    console.log(el); // <li class="accordion-item">...</li>
    // Obtener título, buscando por clase, desde el elemento recibido
    let titulo = el.querySelector('.item-title');
    // Mostrar ID del título
    console.log(titulo.id);           // numero_jornada
    // Mostrar contenido del título
    console.log(titulo.textContent);  // Jornada #

    // Obtener bloque de contenido
    let bloque = el.querySelector('.block'); // <div class="block" id="show-resul-jor-1">...</div>
};
```

Como ves, teniendo el elemento es fácil obtener cualquiera de sus descendientes por algún atributo conocido (etiqueta, class, id, name, etc.).